# Numpy .where function in a 3-D array producing unexpected output

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, satellite-image

I am trying to execute an radiometric and atmoshperic correction on some Landsat 5 TM satellite images - a 6-band stack, entered into a 3 dimensional numpy array arranged as follows: `band, Rows (Lat), Columns(Lon)`.

The issue comes from the empirical method I am trying to use - dark pixel subtraction. The calculation requires the identification in the darkest pixel of the image.

The problem is that in the way the image is arranged in the array it includes the 0 value pixels, which are the, so to say, frame of the image. I wish to exclude these pixels from the image using numpy.where:

```
import numpy as np                               #numerical python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                  #plotting libraries
from pylab import *   
from matplotlib import cm  
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

from spectral.io import envi                     #envi files library

import gdal                                      #Geospatial Data Abstraction Library


#choose the path of the directory with your data
wdir = 'E:/MOMUT1/Bansko_Sat_Img/OutputII/Ipython/stack/'
filename1 = 'Stack_1986.tif'

## open tiff files
data = gdal.Open(wdir+filename1)
tiff_image = data.ReadAsArray()
print(tiff_image.shape)

#exclude one of the bands (thermal band) out of the array
tiff_new = np.zeros((6,7051,7791))
tiff_new[0:4,:,:] = tiff_image[0:4,:,:]
tiff_new[5,:,:] = tiff_image[6,:,:]
del tiff_image


###########
#Convert to TOA (top-of-atmosphere) and surface reflectance

LMAX = [169, 333, 264, 221, 30.2, 16.5] # These are the Landsat calibration coefficients per band
LMIN = [-1.52, -2.84, -1.17, -1.51, -0.37, -0.15];
ESUN = [1983, 1796, 1536, 1031, 220, 83.44]; # These are the solar irradiances per waveband

QCALMAX = 255
QCALMIN = 0

theta=59.40 # Solar zenith angle
DOY=128; # Day of acquisition
d = 1-0.01674*cos(0.9856*(DOY-4)); # This is the formula for the Sun-Earth distance in astronomical units

#create empty matrices (with zeros) to fill in in the loop bellow:
refl_TOA = np.zeros (tiff_new.shape, single)  #same shape as the tiff_new
refl_surf = np.zeros (tiff_new.shape, single)

    for i in range(5):

       im = np.squeeze(tiff_new[i,:,:])#squeezing out the bands out of the array
       im = np.where(im == 0, (NaN) , im)#excluding 0 value pixels
       L = ((LMAX[i] - LMIN[i])/(QCALMAX - QCALMIN))* im + LMIN[i] #This formula calculates radiance from the pixel values
       L = np.single(L) # For memory reason we convert this to single precision
       L1percent = (0.01 * ESUN[i] * np.cos(np.rad2deg(theta))) / (d**2 * pi) # This calculates the theoretical radiance of a dark object as 1 % of the maximum possible radiance 
       Lmini = L.min() # This command finds the darkest pixel in the image
       Lhaze = Lmini - L1percent # The difference between the theoretical 1 % radiance of a dark object and the radiance of the darkest image pixel is due to the atmosphere (this is a simplified empirical method!)
       refl_TOA[i,:,:]=(pi * L  * d**2) / (ESUN[i] * np.cos(np.rad2deg(theta))) # This is the formula for TOA reflectance
       refl_surf[i,:,:]=(pi * (L - Lhaze) * d**2) / (ESUN[i] * np.cos(np.rad2deg(theta))) # This is the formula for surface reflectance in which Lhaze is subtracted from all radiance values

    imshow(refl_surf[1,:,:])
    colorbar()
    show()
```

The code runs, but the output is not as it should be. Instead of the satellite image I see this image:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xng8G.png]

Something in my `.where` statement is not correct, as it seems to be selecting all of the pixels and giving them a `NaN` value, because when I try to check for pixel value by hovering over the image with my mouse courser, no numbers are shown.

Can someone help identifying what is wrong with the way I am using `np.where`?

Comment: Try replacing `(NaN)` with `np.nan`.  Hard to help much without a [mcve]

Comment: I added the minimal, complete and verifiable example. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: also `np.nan` doesn't change the output.

Comment: Not really Complete, since we don't have the `.tif` file to pull test data out of.  Or Minimal, for that matter.  Try to only focus on the code that you think is wrong, input data that can be used to test (and reproduces the problem in the original code), and an expected output.  I often find just the process of asking a good question makes the answer apparent.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am confused at your request? You want me to upload the satellite image (.tif file) to the stack? The code that I know is wrong is the numpy.where statement, as without it the code runs perfectly, but over-corrects the image as it includes those 0 value pixels. In a sense the numpy.where is the only problem, I am sure.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be a Minimal example.  If you think the `np.where` statement is the problem, then give us a (small) dummy `im` array that reproduces the error in that line, and tell us what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is actually here:

```
Lmini = L.min()
```

[`ndarray.min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin) propagates `NaN` values, so when you multiply through by it later you turn your whole array into `NaN`.  You want

```
Lmini = np.nanmin(L)
```

Which will give you the minimum without `NaN` values

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for your suggestion, it did indeed fix the issue with the NaN pixels. The problem now is that the value of the pixel is grounded between -1-0, whereas it should be in the interval 0-1. I don't suppose you have an idea of why this would be so? In any occasion, thanks for your input.

Comment: Think you also have a problem with `theta`.  You define it in degrees (I think), and then use `np.rad2deg`, which converts it to an angle for which  `np.cos` returns a negative.  I think you want `np.deg2rad` instead.

Comment: You turned out to be absolutely right, my friend! That was indeed the problem. `np,cos` takes the arguments in units of radians and not degrees. Thank you!